# woocommerce update _sale_price but dont affected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have alot of products and set discount via sql in foreach:

```
$wpdb->update($aa_products_meta, array(
                'meta_value' => $new_price
            ), array(
                'meta_key' => '_sale_price',
                'post_id' => $product['ID']
            ));
```

it works and each product has new discount price, but disc price does not affected. After save product, him has discount. Seems like wrong price format?
Like string vs int... or?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: 
metafield _price also must be updated and _sale_price must be equal _price